# SQLite TEXT CAST to INTEGER or REAL in C++ Does too much

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite

I'm having trouble casting data types in `TEXT` columns.

I **HAVE** to upload all data from a custom CSV file. There is no guarantee that I'll even get all the columns I expect let alone the right data types so I start with a table where all columns are of type TEXT and put empty strings in the blank spots.

Ex.
Table looks like this

> CREATE TABLE tbl1 ( col1 TEXT, col2 TEXT, col3 TEXT);

After loading `tbl1` from a file I run this.

> SELECT * FROM tbl1;

Select results:

'1','String1', '2.0'

'2','String2', '3.14'

'3','String3', '6.77776'

'h','Stringh', 'h.h'

'','String', ''

Now I want to take the data from `tbl1` and use it to populate this table.

> CREATE TABLE tbl2 ( col1 INTEGER, col2 TEXT, col3 REAL);

And I try it like this.

> INSERT INTO tbl2 SELECT CAST(tbl1.col1 as INTEGER), tbl1.col2, CAST(tbl1.col3 AS REAL) FROM tbl1;

After that I run this,

> SELECT * FROM tbl2;

Select results:

1,'String1', 2.0

2,'String2', 3.14

3,'String3', 6.77776

0,'Stringh', 0

0,'String', 0

What I really want is to grab what I would consider 'Good' casts and insert them into `tbl2` And then take all the values I would consider 'Bad' casts and put them in a 'tbl3' that would look like this.

> CREATE TABLE tbl3 (col1 TEXT, col2 TEXT, col3 TEXT, REASON_FOR_REJECTION TEXT);

`tbl3` would be for reporting and possibly trouble shooting bad data.

Do I need to preprocess this data in C++ before I insert it into `tbl2` or does SQLite support some kind of querying function that allows me to catch 'Bad' casts?

### UPDATE:

By adding CL.'s query to the end of this I could distinguish which records had "Bad" Casts and clean up `tbl2` and add bad data rows to `tbl3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the SQLite [documentation about type affinity](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity).

When you declare a column as `INTEGER` or `REAL`, SQLite will automatically try to convert values.
Any values that cannot be converted will retain the original type.

So just import your data directly into `tbl2`, then find all records with errors with a query like this:

```sql
INSERT INTO tbl3
SELECT col1, col2, col3,
       trim(CASE typeof(col1)
              WHEN 'integer' THEN ''
              ELSE                'col1:' || typeof(col1)
            END ||
            ' ' ||
            CASE typeof(col3)
              WHEN 'real' THEN ''
              ELSE             'col3:' || typeof(col3)
            END)
FROM tbl2
WHERE typeof(col1) != 'integer'
   OR typeof(col3) != 'real'
```

Comment: Quick question this seems to work to populate `tbl3` BUT if I `SELECT * tbl2;` rows `h,stingh,h.h` and `,string,` still show as `0,stingh,0` and `0,string,0`. How would I be able to exclude the records if they are different?

Comment: Never mind. Even though the data was cast to INTEGER and FLOAT it still matches behind the scenes. Confusing but Awesome! so a `select tbl2.*, tbl3.* from tbl2, tbl3 where tbl2.col1 = tbl3.col1 AND tbl2.col2 = tbl3.col2 AND tbl2.col3 = tbl3.col3;` does find something.