# SQLite Binding Numaric Datatype

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, sqlite

I'm trying to update some code I have to use Binding Instead of native Queries.

I'm using the the [ETL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) model to load this data.

It all starts with me creating a table with all columns defined as Text.

```
Create Table TableA ( Col1 Text, Col2 Text);
```

I then populate the table using native queries like,

```
INSERT INTO TABLEA ('A', '2');
INSERT INTO TABLEA ('B', 'Bad_VALUE_Not_INT');
```

I then create a real data table

```
 Create Table RealTableA ( Col1 Text, Col2 Integer);
```

And then insert the values into the real table and Delete ones with the wrong datatype as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15219356/839501)

```
INSERT INTO RealTableA SELECT * FROM TABLEA;

DELETE FROM RealTableA WHERE typeof(col2) != 'integer'
```

This works great when I wrote the queries and submitted them natively. But I now want to Bind Variables to a statement instead of using Native Queries as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1711631/839501)

So I changed the code to use `sqlite3_bind_text` with a [prepared_statement](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html).

Now SQLite thinks every value in `col2` is really `'text'` when I query using `typeof(col2)` this is erasing **EVERYTHING**.

I find this strange because of the example of type affinity SQLite has [here](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity).

How do I fix this without rewriting all my ETL queries after the initial load?

I found a binding function called `sqlite3_bind_value` who's definition sounds like it will treat the values bound to it as `numeric` which is what I want. The problem is it takes a `SQLite3_value*` and I can't for the life of me figure out how to make text values from a file into that.

Ideas? Am I way off with this approach?

Also why is it when I bind values they get a hard 'TEXT' type designation but when I insert into a 'TEXT' column it allows some wiggle room for other types?

Note: I'm using the C/C++ interface with Visual Studios 2010 and I'm on version 3.7.13 of SQLite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sqlite3_bind_value` works only with such values that you get from SQLite, which happens only with parameters of user-defined functions.

To bind other types than text, use the appropriate [sqlite3_bind_xxx function](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html), e.g., `sqlite3_bind_int`.

Comment: I'm aware of the other bind functions but I'm in a situation where I have to store everything I'm given which makes storing it as text logical. Then after I do that I can go through and take the valid data to actually process with. So there is no bind that works like the default column type Numaric for data you have?

Comment: Appears that I had the size of the text value wrong and once I used strlen() on it white space filler disappeared and everything went back to normal. I'm giving you the answer because it's when I reread the bind documentation you linked that I noticed I'd done it wrong.