# .import csv sqlite data type and size issues

Tags: sqlite, csv

I have a big csv file with five columns, one date and four doubles.

With `.import my.csv newtable` all columns have `TEXT` type.

With `CREATE TABLE mytable(date TEXT, d1 REAL, d2 REAL, d3 REAL, d4 REAL);` and `.import --skip 1 my.csv mytable` `.schema mytable` shows correct schema.

The problem is, `.save my.db` produces databases of same size in both cases, which makes me doubt that it saved double fields correctly. Moreover, `.import my.csv mytable` (without `--skip 1`) assigns strings to d1 - d4 of first row, which are `REAL` according to schema.

Also, `my.db` weighs significantly more than `my.csv` for some reason, 976M vs 808M, which is also bizzare.

Can i import csv correctly? If not, can I at least run some cast/substitution on the whole columns?

UPDATE:

According to [SQLite TEXT CAST to INTEGER or REAL in C++ Does too much](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15214102/sqlite-text-cast-to-integer-or-real-in-c-does-too-much#15219356) it seems that sqlite should be converting to `REAL` in my second case, but file size issue still bugs me.

Comment: Creating and populating a a table via `.import` from a .csv file uses all text values, yes. If the table already exists, values are converted according to column affinities. Did you look at the file generated by `.save`?

Comment: Yes and it had correct number of rows with correct data, but too big.

Comment: Size has nothing to do with anything. Are the values numeric literals or strings? (Or am I thinking of `.dump`? Use `typeof()` to see what type is used in an actual DB query)